# How to find command by shortcut and disable it in Kubuntu?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut, ubuntu

many commands in Intellij IDEA do not work in Kubuntu. I think that Kubuntu catch their... I wanna disable this shortcut in OS, but i don't know how find it.

Answer (score 0):

open system settings -> shortcuts-and-gestures and on 3th tab you can find global keyboard shortcuts.
Hope that will help you, good luck.